# Copy data from cygwin window to another cygwin window

Tags: cygwin

I'm having 2 cygwin windows opened.
Is there a way I can transfer data between the 2 windows?

I try to write a script that setting some envs on the second window, based on envs that were set in the first cygwin window.

I though about creating a file in the first window, and then the script that will be run in the second window can go to that file, read the data and set the envs according.

But I prefer a better solution, if possible without including files.

Thank you

Comment: copy on clipboard, read from clipboard ?

Comment: https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fcygutils-extra%2Fcygutils-extra-1.4.17-1&grep=bin%2Fputclip

Comment: There are programs called `getclip.exe` and `putclip.exe` which read or write to the windows clipboard. They are in a package called `cygutils-extras`. (Ty to @matzeri for clarifying my original post.)